# Canvas/JS banner with Flash

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Here is my first Canvas/JS banner. I just got a flash one and hand-coded it from the beginning to the end.

I have several major concerns/questions:

1. I have seen several banners made in Adobe Flash, despite there being several external libraries are used (which is not cool in my case). There is also only ONE canvas, so how is it possible to make complex animations with one canvas only?
2. It is extremely sluggish on mobile devices (this code doesn't have it but, of course, the latest shim is used).
3. Where can I see a professionally made standard HTML5 banner code? I'm just curious about how it looks as I suppose canvas use is not a dogm.
4. I know the code needs tons of improvements, so I'd like improvements. I do not ask to improve the banner; I just need more info on what is wrong and what should be improved.

```
function RoundNum(num, length) {
    var number = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, length)) / Math.pow(10, length);
    return number;
}
// CONTROLS
var speed = '100';
var circw = '100';
var circh = '185';

var txtw = '100';
var txth = '185';

var cancel = '';

var canvasImage = document.getElementById("image");
var ctxImage = canvasImage.getContext("2d");

var canvasCircle = document.getElementById("redCircle");
var ctxRedCircle = canvasCircle.getContext("2d");


var canvasWhiteCircle = document.getElementById("whiteCircle");
var ctxWhiteCircle = canvasWhiteCircle.getContext("2d");


var blueCan = document.getElementById('blueText');
var blue = blueCan.getContext('2d');


var txtCanvas = document.getElementById('text');
var textOne = txtCanvas.getContext('2d');


var blueCanSld = document.getElementById('blues');
var bluectx = blueCanSld.getContext('2d');


var BlueTxtCanvas = document.getElementById('blueText');
var blueText = BlueTxtCanvas.getContext('2d');


var botCan = document.getElementById('blues');
var blueBot = botCan.getContext('2d');


var canlogo = document.getElementById('logo');
var logoctx = canlogo.getContext('2d');


var buttonCan = document.getElementById('button');
var button = buttonCan.getContext('2d');


var legalCan = document.getElementById('legaltxt');
var legal = legalCan.getContext('2d');


var memberCan = document.getElementById('legal');
var memberTxt = memberCan.getContext('2d');


var canRep = document.getElementById('replay');
var replay = canRep.getContext('2d');


// blue fade in
blue.globalAlpha = 0.85;

function blueFadeIn() {
    if (blue.globalAlpha > 0.010000284761190414) {
        blue.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        blue.globalAlpha += -0.02;

        blue.rect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        blue.fillStyle = '#005aa9';
        blue.fill();

        requestAnimationFrame(blueFadeIn);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {

            blue.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
            white();

        }, 101);
    }

}

blueFadeIn();

// blue fade in ends here                       


// IMG scale


var img = new Image();
var w = 450;
var h = 375;
var wzoom = 1;
var hzoom = 1;
img.onload = function () {
    // step it down only once to 1/6 size:
    ctxImage.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w / wzoom, h / hzoom);

    function show() {
        if (wzoom < 2) {
            wzoom += 0.0005;
            hzoom += 0.0005;
            ctxImage.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w / wzoom, h / hzoom);
            cancel = requestAnimationFrame(show);
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(show);

}

img.src = 'http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/BB_Tablet_INVESTb_big.jpg';

// end of IMG scale


// white circle animation
var radius = 0;

function white() {
    ctxWhiteCircle.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
    ctxWhiteCircle.beginPath();
    ctxWhiteCircle.arc(circw, circh, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctxWhiteCircle.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctxWhiteCircle.lineWidth = 1;
    ctxWhiteCircle.stroke();
    ctxWhiteCircle.closePath();

    if (radius < 90) {

        radius += 5;
        requestAnimationFrame(white);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            red();
        }, 1);
    }
}

// end of white circle animation

// drawing Red Circle   

var redRadius = 5;

function red() {
    ctxRedCircle.beginPath();
    ctxRedCircle.globalAlpha = 0.85;
    ctxRedCircle.arc(circw, circh, redRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctxRedCircle.fillStyle = "#e2231a";

    ctxRedCircle.fill();
    ctxRedCircle.closePath();


    if (redRadius < 85) {
        redRadius += 3;
        requestAnimationFrame(red);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            txtEins();

        }, 1);
    }

}

// end of the Red Circle Block



// TEXT #1      


function txtEins() {


    textOne.globalAlpha = 0;

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        (function loop() {

            textOne.globalAlpha += 0.055;

            textOne.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
            textOne.drawImage(img, txtw - 57, txth - 40);
            var opacity = RoundNum(textOne.globalAlpha, 2);
            if (opacity < 0.99) {
                requestAnimationFrame(loop);
                //alert(textOne.globalAlpha);               
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    textOne.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
                    txtZwei();
                }, speed);
            }
        })();

    }
    img.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/txt_01.png"
}

// TEXT #2



function txtZwei() {

    textOne.globalAlpha = 0;

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        (function loop() {
            textOne.globalAlpha += 0.055;
            textOne.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
            textOne.drawImage(img, txtw - 57, txth - 30);

            var opacity = RoundNum(textOne.globalAlpha, 2);
            if (opacity < 0.99) {
                requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    textOne.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
                    //redOff();
                    txtDrei();
                }, speed);
            }
        })();

    }
    img.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/txt_02.png"
}

// TEXT #3      

function txtDrei() {

    textOne.globalAlpha = 0;

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        (function loop() {
            textOne.globalAlpha += 0.055;
            textOne.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
            textOne.drawImage(img, txtw - 57, txth - 30);

            var opacity = RoundNum(textOne.globalAlpha, 2);
            if (opacity < 0.99) {
                requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    textOne.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
                    redOff();
                    window.cancelAnimationFrame(cancel);
                }, speed);
            }
        })();

    }
    img.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/txt_03.png"
}


// TEXT #3 OFF


// RED FADE OUT

var redius = 85;

function redOff() {

    ctxRedCircle.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
    ctxRedCircle.beginPath();
    ctxRedCircle.globalAlpha = 0.85;
    ctxRedCircle.arc(circw, circh, redius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctxRedCircle.fillStyle = "#e223001a";

    ctxRedCircle.fill();
    ctxRedCircle.closePath();


    if (redius > 0) {
        redius += -5;
        requestAnimationFrame(redOff);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            whiteOff();
        }, 1);
    }

}

// RED FADE OUT ENDS HERE



// WHITE CIRCLE OFF



var radiusOff = 85;

function whiteOff() {
    ctxWhiteCircle.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
    ctxWhiteCircle.beginPath();
    ctxWhiteCircle.arc(circw, circh, radiusOff, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctxWhiteCircle.strokeStyle = '#fff';
    ctxWhiteCircle.lineWidth = 1;
    ctxWhiteCircle.stroke();
    ctxWhiteCircle.closePath();

    if (radiusOff > 0) {

        radiusOff += -5;
        requestAnimationFrame(whiteOff);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            blueSlide();
        }, 1);
    }
}

// END OF WHITE CIRCLE OFF

// BLUE BG SLIDES               

bluex = 300;
bluectx.globalAlpha = 0.85;

function blueSlide() {
    if (bluex > 0) {

        bluectx.clearRect(bluex, 0, 300, 250);
        bluex += -10;
        bluectx.beginPath();
        bluectx.rect(bluex, 0, 300, 250);
        bluectx.fillStyle = '#005aa9';
        bluectx.fill();
        requestAnimationFrame(blueSlide);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            blueTxt();
        }, 1);
    }


}


// blue fade in ends here

// blue text    

function blueTxt() {

    blueText.globalAlpha = 0;


    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/txt_04.png";
    img.onload = function () {
        (function loop() {
            blueText.globalAlpha += 0.1;
            blueText.clearRect(0, 0, BlueTxtCanvas.width, BlueTxtCanvas.height);
            blueText.drawImage(img, 31, 26);

            if (blueText.globalAlpha < 0.900000095367430016) {
                requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            } else {
                setTimeout(function () {

                    bottomLine();


                }, 1);
            }
        })();

    }

}
// blue text ends   

// BOTTOM LINE SLIDE            


var y = 250;

function bottomLine() {

    if (y > 185) {

        y += -5;

        //blueBot.clearRect(0,0,300,250);
        blueBot.beginPath();
        blueBot.rect(0, y, 300, 65);
        blueBot.fillStyle = '#0079c2';
        blueBot.fill();
        requestAnimationFrame(bottomLine);
        blueBot.closePath();
    } else {
        blueBot.beginPath();
        blueBot.rect(0, 175, 300, 10);
        blueBot.fillStyle = '#fff';
        blueBot.fill();
        blueBot.closePath();

        buttonus();
    }
}

// BUTTON

function buttonus() {


    buttonCan.addEventListener("click", function () {
        window.open('http://bmo.com', '_blank');
    });

    buttonCan.addEventListener("mouseover", btnRollover, false);
    buttonCan.addEventListener("mouseout", btnRollOff, false);

    function btnRollover() {
        button.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);

        var cta = new Image();

        cta.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/cta2.png"
        cta.onload = function () {
            button.drawImage(cta, 0, 0);
        }

    }


    function btnRollOff() {
        button.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);

        var cta = new Image();

        cta.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/cta.png"
        cta.onload = function () {
            button.drawImage(cta, 0, 0);
        }

    }




    button.globalAlpha = 0;

    function buttonFadeIn() {
        if (button.globalAlpha < 0.9500001668930054) {
            button.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
            button.globalAlpha += 0.05;

            var cta = new Image();

            cta.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/cta.png"
            cta.onload = function () {
                button.drawImage(cta, 0, 0);

            }


            //alert(button.globalAlpha);

            requestAnimationFrame(buttonFadeIn);
        } else {

            setTimeout(function () {
                logo();

            }, 14);
        }


    }
    buttonFadeIn();
}


// BUTTON ENDS
function logo() {

    // LOGO             

    var imgbmo = new Image();

    imgbmo.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/logo_tm.png"
    imgbmo.onload = function () {
        logoctx.drawImage(imgbmo, 30, 190);
    }

    rePlay();
    legalus();
}

// LOGO ENDS


// LEGAL    
function legalus() {


    legalCan.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        legal.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 120);

        legalshow();
    });
    legalCan.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
        memberTxt.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 175);
        var legalimg = new Image();

        legalimg.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/legal.png"
        legalimg.onload = function () {
            //legal.drawImage(legalimg,240,159);
            legal.drawImage(legalimg, 0, 0);
        }
    });


    var legalimg = new Image();

    legalimg.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/legal.png"
    legalimg.onload = function () {
        //legal.drawImage(legalimg,240,159);
        legal.drawImage(legalimg, 0, 0);
    }

}

// LEGAL OVERLAY


function legalshow()

{

    memberTxt.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 175);
    memberTxt.globalAlpha = 0.9;
    memberTxt.beginPath();
    memberTxt.fillStyle = "#000";
    memberTxt.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 175);
    memberTxt.lineWidth = 5;
    memberTxt.strokeStyle = "#c7c7c6";
    memberTxt.stroke();
    memberTxt.fillStyle = "#fff";
    memberTxt.font = "10pt Franklin Gothic";
    //var textWidth = memberTxt.measureText(text).width;
    memberTxt.fillText('Member of the Investment Industry', 31, 58);
    memberTxt.fillText('Regulatory Organization of Canada', 31, 75);

}
// LEGAL ENDS 

function rePlay() {

    var repimg = new Image();

    repimg.src = "http://a5w.org/banner/5/images/replay.png"
    repimg.onload = function () {
        //legal.drawImage(legalimg,240,159);
        replay.drawImage(repimg, 245, 10);
    }

    canRep.addEventListener("click", function () {
        replay.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);

        bluectx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        blueBot.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        logoctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        button.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        legal.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        memberTxt.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
        replay.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 250);

        init();
    });
}
```